# How to auto-increment in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table Login. It has the fields rank, username and password.

I want the rank field value to be auto incremented with respect to addition of username and password.

How do I do this in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Btw, you have a small typing error in your question. It's increment not increament. If you change it, more people will find this question, plus the related questions will be more appropriate.

Comment: This is about an existing table, while the other question is more about new tables IMO. So it's not really a duplicate, unless you merge them.

Comment: As of PostgreSQL 10, the recommended way is to use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY generated always as identity` instead of `SERIAL`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A Sequence can be created which will auto increment the value of rank column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE rank_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE yourtable (
    rank INTEGER NOT NULL default nextval('rank_id_seq'),
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER SEQUENCE rank_id_seq owned by yourtable.rank;
```

Answer (score 49):

You are looking for a column with datatype `Serial`. See [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (bottom) for more information about that datatype.

So for example, your table definition could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
    rank SERIAL NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: @Milen A. Radev, thanks for adding that anchor to my link :)

Comment: The autoincrement works like this: `insert into yourtable (username, password) values ('moobars', 'boobars');`  Then the database autoincrements the rank column.

Comment: SERIAL is not a datatype, just an alias for an integer with a sequence as default (see Sanjay Kumar's asnwer)

Answer (score 4):

```
create table login (rank serial, username varchar(20), password varchar(20))
```

Serial datatype is what you want.