# How to use autogenerated ID in JdbcBatchItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-batch

I'm using `Spring` `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to flush lots of data to a postgres DB.

`INSERT INTO customer (id, name, zip) VALUES (?,?,?)`

I only set name + zip as I want the id to be auto generated. But how can I let the db autogenerate the id value? If I execute the statement above, the DB complains as the id is not set.

```
@Entity
class Customer {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   long id;
}
```

Comment: Don't include the `id` column in your insert statement. Only include name and `zip`. `INSERT INTO customer (name, zip) values (?,?)`.

Comment: I tried this before of course and it gives the error: `ERROR : PSQLException: ERROR: NULL-value in column ?id? violates Not-Null-Constraint`

Comment: Create your tables correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718585/set-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108777/how-to-auto-increment-in-postgresql for 2 possible solutions.

Comment: The table is autogenerated by hibernate as I also work with the entities within the application: `CREATE TABLE customer
(
id bigint NOT NULL,
 name character varying(255),
 zip character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));` But I'd also like to make batch imports with the JdbcBatchItemWriter. So I don't want to create the DB tables myself, anyhow I'd like the id to be autogenerated.

Comment: Letting hibernate auto-generate your schema, for production, is generally a bad idea. I don't believe the `@GeneratedValue` will be added to your create table statement. If your inserts work with plain hibernate/jpa then why not use a `JpaItemWriter` or `Hibernate ItemWriter`?

Comment: Indeed the `@GeneratedValue` will result in a `SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence` generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

`INSERT INTO customer (id, name, zip) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), ?, ?)`

Comment: You should be aware when changing your database, because i think `nextval` is a custom oracle function

Comment: @OussamaZoghlami No, it's a built-in PostgreSQL function. If you're talking about changing to a different database vendor, then yes, this code is specific to the PostgreSQL dialect, but when you're bypassing Hibernate you're going to be dealing with that anyway.